# Run Junit 5 on Docker using Testcontainers java

Tags: docker, junit5, testcontainers

I want to run tests using testcontainers containers on docker.
I tried to google any examples for it, and now I have some code, but it doesn't work to achieve my goal. Do you have any tipps etc. or could you maybe refactor the code below, that it works(it runs containers for each test method, migrate tables from Postgres etc.)?

```
class CourseDaoImplTest {

private static PostgreSQLContainer<?> container;
private DataSource ds;
private CourseDaoImpl courseDao = new CourseDaoImpl(ds);
private DbTestUtils dbTestUtils;
private final static String DOCKER_IMAGE = "postgres";
   
@BeforeAll
public static void setupContainer() throws SQLException {
    try (PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(DOCKER_IMAGE))
            .withDatabaseName("schoolconsoleapp")
            .withUsername("postgres")
            .withPassword("user")) {
        container.start();           
    }
       
}

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    String url = container.getJdbcUrl();
    
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        connection.createStatement().executeQuery("INSERT INTO courses(course_name, course_description) VALUES ('German', 'Learn german language')");
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static DataSource createDataSource(JdbcDatabaseContainer container) {
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(container.getJdbcUrl());
    hikariConfig.setUsername(container.getUsername());
    hikariConfig.setPassword(container.getPassword());
    
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}

private static ResultSet performQuery(DataSource ds, String query) throws SQLException {
    Statement st = ds.getConnection().createStatement();
    st.execute(query);
    
    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
    rs.next();
    return rs;    
}

@Test
public void shouldBeReturnedTrue_whenContainerIsRunning() {
    String url = container.getJdbcUrl(); 
    assertTrue(container.isRunning());
    assertEquals("", url);
}
```

}

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into?  Can you use a lighter-weight solution, like an in-memory database (H2 or HDBC) or a mock implementation of your JPA entity interfaces?  (IME Testcontainers is kinda slow with lots of tests, the setup can be occasionally finicky, and your security team might not like giving out unrestricted root access on the CI systems.)

Comment: The problem is, that I have a Postgres DB and I need to test JDBC CRUD operations. As I unterstand, a common practice to test such method is to run the db on containers. So I would like to learn how can do this.